# Issue with Test Cases when executed as a whole

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

If I execute the test cases on EBY one they work, but if I execute the test Suite the results I received are just random, sometimes the TestCases Might work and other times don't.

I tried with explicit waits to see if it's the responding time.
Also, to verify TestCase by test case to see if there was something wrong.

```java
{
        driver.get(Constant.VTenantURL);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        BlockUI_Wait.Execute(driver);
        WebElement TestTenant = driver.findElement(By.linkText("TC 1839 Tenant Creation"));
        TestTenant.click();
        BlockUI_Wait.Execute(driver);
        Manage_VTenants.VTUsers(driver).click();WebElement Add = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tab_users_domain\"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/i"));
        Add.click();Manage_VTenants.VTAddItem3(driver).click();
        BlockUI_Wait.Execute(driver);
        Save_Action.Execute(driver);
}
```

I wish to know a better way or best practices to implement in order to received reliable data from the results.